# NumPy Data w/ TensorFlow "Not on the same graph"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

So i'm trying to build a model that takes in an image-like numpy file and builds a model based on the data. Each individual .npy file DOES fit in memory, however I need to assume that all loaded at the same time will not.

When I go to run it & do a test evaluation, it gives me this error:

`ValueError: Tensor("IteratorV2:0", shape=(), dtype=resource) must be from the same graph as Tensor("MapDataset:0", shape=(), dtype=variant)`

I'm not super experienced with TensorFlow and I'm trying to make everything as "best practice" as possible.

Here's my code:

```
train_fnames, train_labels, test_fnames, test_labels =\
    spec_to_paths_and_labels('count_data/spec.csv')
train_fnames = 'count_data/' + train_fnames
test_fnames = 'count_data/' + test_fnames


def read_npy_file(item):
    data = np.load(item.decode())
    return data.astype(np.int32)


# gdsii_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 224, 224, 1))
# label_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1])


def cnn_model(features, labels, mode):
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(features, filters=32, kernel_size=(5, 5))
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool1, filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5))
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)

    flat = tf.layers.flatten(pool2)

    dense = tf.layers.dense(flat, units=1024, activation='relu')
    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=True)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

    predictions = {
        "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
        "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    }
    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)


def main(_):
    # load the dataset
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_fnames)
    data = data.map(lambda item: tuple(tf.py_func(
        read_npy_file, [item], [tf.int32, ])))

    gdsii_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=cnn_model, model_dir="/tmp/gdsii_classifier")

    res = gdsii_classifier.evaluate(lambda: data)
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several little mistakes in your code:

First, you tried to use `Estimator` without wrapping your `tf.data` operations inside an input function. This causes an issue because `tf.data` operations create their own graph for data loading while `Estimator` expects to have all the control on the whole graph. When you then call `estimator.evaluate()`, it fails because the tensor is inside your previously built graph.

Secondly, you tried to call `estimator.evaluate()` without a label.

Then, after you use a `tf.py_func` in `tf.data`, you need to specify the shape of the different tensors as they can't be inferred by Tensorflow.

And finally, you need to batch your data as `tf.layers` expect `ndims=4`, and you need to pass the features as either `float32` or `float16`.

You can easily patch these issues by doing something like this:

```
def input_fn(x, y):
    def set_shape(tensor, shape):
        tensor.set_shape(shape)
        return tensor

    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    data = data.map(lambda item, label: (tf.py_func(read_npy_file, [item], [tf.float32]), label))
    data = data.map(lambda item, label: (set_shape(item, YOUR_SHAPE), label))
    data = data.batch(1)

    return data

...
estimator.evaluate(lambda: input_fn(x=test_fnames, y=test_labels))
```